# What does Fagin's result say about NP $\ne$ co-NP?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

I'm no expert in this area, and not trying to solve P vs. NP, just trying to understand a formulation of NP.

It seems like Fagin's result 1974 is saying that NP is the class of structures axiomatizable in existential second-order logic, that is $\Sigma_1^1$.  Then co-NP would be $\Pi_1^1$.  But I thought that if NP $\ne$ co-NP then P $\ne$ NP.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P is closed under complementation.  If NP $\neq$ co-NP, then NP is not closed under complementation. So then P and NP can't be the same.

Comment: Thanks Andreas!  I was wondering why can't we conclude from Fagin's result that NP $\ne$ co-NP?

Comment: We could conclude that **if** we knew that $\Sigma^1_1$ and $\Pi^1_1$ are different on finite structures. But we don't know that.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that they might be the same.  But we do know that $\Sigma_1^1 \cap \Pi_1^1 = \Delta_1^1$ on finite structures?

Comment: I regard the equation $\Sigma^1_1\cap\Pi^1_1=\Delta^1_1$ as the definition of $\Delta^1_1$. More generally I regard any  $\Delta$ class as being defined as the intersection of the corresponding $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ classes. .

Comment: I see, thank you. Is it correct to say that the computing power of a Turing machine is a subset of $\Delta_1^1$ on finite structures but we do not know if it is a proper subset?

Comment: @ErinCarmody No, Turing machines can do vastly more than that. In the finite realm, second-order logic is incredibly *weak* compared to full computability: just think about brute-force-searching through the powerset. (Actually you already have this, since NP - a tiny fragment of "computable" - corresponds to $\Sigma^1_1$ as stated in your question.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass That said, given that $\Delta^1_1$ isn't a syntactic class there is a subtlety here (writing "$Mod(-)$" and "$Mod_{fin}(-)$" for the classes of models and of finite models of a sentence respectively): I don't think it's quite trivial that, if $\varphi,\psi$ are $\Sigma^1_1$ sentences with $Mod_{fin}(\varphi)\sqcup Mod_{fin}(\psi)=Mod_{fin}(\top)$, then there are $\varphi',\psi'\in\Sigma^1_1$ such that $Mod_{fin}(\varphi)=Mod_{fin}(\varphi')$, $Mod_{fin}(\psi)=Mod_{fin}(\psi')$, and $Mod(\varphi')\sqcup Mod(\psi')=Mod(\top)$. Or is that obvious and I'm being slow?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah sorry I think I mean computing power of a Turing machine in polynomial time?

Comment: @ErinCarmody Ah, in that case yes. That makes more sense!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, great!